How could the FBI interfere with a local investigation?
In The Departed, it is revealed that Costello is an FBI informant. Costigan says that this is why the state police always try to set up a case against him and they always fail.
In what ways can the FBI hamper a local investigation?

They can contact the DA and just ask them nicely not to prosecute.

@Valorum Why would the DA obey the FBI?

Because contrary to popular belief, the American system of justice isn't a contradicting mess run by morons. Differing branches of state and federal authorities frequently cooperate even if there's no legal requirement to do so.

Considering that in the movie the two authorities don't cooperate, what kind of excuse would the DA give to the state force to not prosecute Costello? Something like "the evidence you guys have is not good enough"?

This sounds like a question about the American justice system, not the film, which only serves as a motive. How are the different ways in which the FBI can hamper local investigations important for your understanding of the film?

In the world of American television and movies (not sure about the real world), when the FBI is building a federal case against a person or organization, they often request that state and municipal law enforcement agencies refrain from harassing, arresting, or prosecuting the targets of their investigation.
The reason given is generally that a non-FBI investigation could cause the criminals to change their methods or otherwise do something that would ruin the work done by the FBI to build a case.
The reasons why state and municipal law enforcement would agree to step back and allow the FBI to pursue their case unhindered are not always made clear in TV shows and movies, but generally there is at least an implication of politics. It could be the governor, mayor, or chief of police feels that it would hurt them politically to be in conflict with the FBI. Sometimes, it is shown that a person working in local law enforcement has aspirations to become an FBI agent as part of their career, and those plans could be derailed if it comes out that they hampered an FBI investigation.
One ultimate reason sometimes given is that federal prosecution and sentencing is often more comprehensive and severe, so local law enforcement personnel who desire the most severe punishment for criminals will allow a federal case to supersede their local case. Sometimes we see local prosecutors and police threaten suspects with handing off their case to "the feds", with the implication that the greater resources of federal law enforcement will result in a worse outcome for the suspect compared with a plea bargain with the local DA.
A review of the Wikipedia page on the RICO Act does suggest that federal prosecution for organized crime activity can lead to severe sentences that may not be available under state or local laws. (The Departed depicts a criminal organization whose members could be prosecuted under the RICO Act.)
Another thing Valorum seems to be right about is that according to the FBI web site, in the real world, federal and local agencies team up on investigations, they do not fight each other.

In the movie, the state police is unaware that they are being hampered. Maybe the FBI doesn't want to disclose their investigation. How would the FBI and the DA conceal their hampering?

@Alexandre Are you asking how it would be done in real life? It seems like it wouldn’t. Are you asking how it was done in the movie? I’m not sure that’s made clear
